# Highcharts : How to remove the gap between series and vertical axis?

Tags: highcharts

It seems like Highcharts is adding some spacing between the 1. series line start/series line end and the 2. vertical axis.

Please see the jsfiddle link and below screenshot for more details.

http://jsfiddle.net/8kbf2e1x/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

[image: Highcharts - auto added gaps]

How do I get rid of this spaces? I want my series lines to expand from ened to end within the plot area with no gaps. Is it achievable with smaller number of data points? (e.g. in my case every series has only 4 data points)

Comment: This is probably the most asked question in Highcharts history: https://www.google.com/search?q=Highcharts+%3A+How+to+remove+the+gap+between+series+and+vertical+axis%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 6):

check [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.pointPlacement)

when pointPlacement is "on", the point will not create any padding of the X axis.

```
 plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kbf2e1x/) demo

Comment: This still have the gap https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRThW.png