# Highcharts - Areaspline chart minPadding dose not work with categories array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Ii am using below configuration for areaspline chart

```
xAxis: {
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        categories: [
            'Monday',
            'Tuesday'
        ],
},
```

And jsfiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/k08u6mnh/5/

I want to remove blank space on sides of the chart. If we remove categories array it works as expected. But I need specific categories.

Does anyone has any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts x-axis tick starts with an offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364906/highcharts-x-axis-tick-starts-with-an-offset)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts : How to remove the gap between series and vertical axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425104/highcharts-how-to-remove-the-gap-between-series-and-vertical-axis)

Comment: check this working demo https://jsfiddle.net/8xbm90hx/

Comment: Thank you @Deep3015 the demo you shared worked for me! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you @ewolden. The link to the solution you shared also does the job! Really appreciate your help.